# How to approach this problem on limits and Euclidean metrics?

Tags: general-topology

How is it that we have $\lim _\limits{n \rightarrow \infty} d\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right)=d(x, y),$?

Comment: This is true in any metric space. Use triangle in equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d(x_k, y_k) \le d(x_k, x) + d(x,y) + d(y, y_k)$ so

$d(x_k, y_k)- d(x,y) \le d(x_k,x) + d(y_k,y)$.

Also

$d(x, y) \le d(x, x_k) + d(x_k,y_k) + d(y_k, y)$ so

$d(x, y)- d(x_k,y_k) \le d(x_k,x) + d(y_k,y)$.

In conclusion (as $|u|=\max(u,-u)$):

$$|d(x, y)- d(x_k,y_k)| \le d(x_k,x) + d(y_k,y)\tag{1}$$

Now, if $\varepsilon>0$, for $k \ge N_1$ we have $d(x_k, x) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and for $k \ge N_2$ we have $d(y_k, y) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, for some $N_1,N_2 \in \Bbb N$, by the convergences $x_k \to x$ and $y_k \to y$.

Then $(1)$ implies that for $k \ge N:=\max(N_1,N_2)$ we have

$$|d(x, y)- d(x_k,y_k)| < \varepsilon$$ showing the convergence of the (real) sequence $d(x_k,y_k)$ to $d(x,y)$.

This is often just expressed as "the distance is a continuous function", for short. It's a handy fact in many proofs.

Comment: Thank you!! I have a question. Is it necessary to show the first part of your answer: (,)≤(,)+(,)+(,)  so

(,)−(,)≤(,)+(,). I feel that the "Also, (,)≤(,)+(,)+(,)  so

(,)−(,)≤(,)+(,)." states the same thing.

Comment: @Lily you need both because the absolute value is the maximum of these differences.

Comment: I see. I am also wondering how in "||=max(,−)" what this  is referring to?

Comment: @Lily $u$ is any  real number. The difference of distances e.g.

Comment: I see. I am still slightly confused as to how the transition from ||=max(,−) to (1) occurred. Why is it that (1) is the maximum difference of the distances?

Comment: For instance, would the proof still work if we used (,)−(,)≤(,)+(,) instead of (1)?

Comment: @Lily You need the distance of the distances, so $|d(x_k, y_k)-d(x,y)|$. This number either equals $d(x_k, y_k)-d(x,y)$ or its negative $d(x,y)-d(x_k,y_k)$ and both are bounded by $d(x_k,x)+ d(y_k,y)$, so the absolute value too.

Comment: I completely understand now. Thank you for your clarification!

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $y_n \rightarrow y$ mean that:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \| x_n - x \| = 0$$
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \| y_n - y \| = 0$$
Now use triangle inequality:
$$ \| a + b \| \leq \| a \| + \| b \|$$
to prove the statement.